# Change offset of geotiff file

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, geotiff

I need to change the offset of some tiff files that I am exporting from Qgis. 
Qgis gives them a offset of 0xbd72, while the program I need to load them in to only reades files with an offset of 0xbcde.

Does anyone know how to change the offset of a tiff file in Qgis or python/gdal or any other way?

(I am trying to make a dtm of same shape as the srtm from ace2-data, north of 60deg, for use in Compass C-Pilot, a flight instrument for paragliding. It needs data in offset 0xbcde and 0x2ee2 bytes per row.)

Comment: Although this question is a good fit for this site (GIS), it is likely it will get more and timelier answers on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Since GDAL is the software that configures and writes the data, [take a look at the technical manual](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html). In particular, see the *creation options* section, where there are many options that affect the resulting file. Also, it's not clear what you mean by "offset", so you need to clarify it. Also, with the ideal TIFF file, run

```
gdalinfo example.tif
```

to get an idea of the ideal structure.